# html file is not showing using streamreader on codebehind

Tags: c#

I wanted to display `.html` file on my content page but it's not displaying instead it gives an error like

> "The resource cannot be found."

I stored my sample.html on Temp folder.
I'm trying to use the keyword using, `streamreader` and `iframe`.

this is what I've done so far. Please enlighten me.

```
using (StreamReader streamrd = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("/Temp/sample.html")))
{
    my_iframe.Attributes["src"] = ""+streamrd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code,

1. You're trying to concatenate a string with streamreader which will print out [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://rextester.com/CGV74444) meaning that the `src` attribute in your iFrame will have that value.
2. You're trying to put the contents of a file into a `src` attribute which should contain a URL instead. [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_src.asp)

You should get the file path ( server one ) and put it inside of yoru iFrame's `src` attribute, something like that:

```
my_iframe.Attributes["src"] = Server.MapPath("/Temp/sample.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need somewhat like this:
Responce.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Temp/sample.html")));